# Object-aware custom picklist on LWC property datasource

Tags: lightning-web-components

Happy `Datetime.now().format('EEEE')`!  I'm working on an LWC that has a few configuration properties exposed.  What I would like to do is have a picklist of values that lists all the lookup fields on the object, e.g. for any given object Lightning Page Layout we can have something like:

[image]

I love the idea that I can set the picklist values dynamically (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm) but what I really need here is awareness of what object I'm working with.  I might put this component on a Contact page layout or an Opportunity page layout and I would need to know that so I can build the correct list of lookup-type field names.

Is there any way to do this or do I need to figure out some other kind of workaround, or does anyone have any great ideas?  I did find this doc that talks about using objectApiName, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_object_context, but it only looks like I can use an expression like this in Expression Builder and not Lightning App Builder (I've tried, it fails telling you as much).  Also, I found this answer to a similar question which confirmed that behavior, [How to set attribute in the designer to a string-value which contains expression-tokens like "{!...}"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214251/how-to-set-attribute-in-the-designer-to-a-string-value-which-contains-expression).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  All I needed was 10 minutes more.  Here's my solution in case it can help anyone else.

It turns out the `VisualEditor.DesignTimePageContext` class is exactly what I needed, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_VisualEditor_DesignTimePageContext.htm.  Using this I know exactly what object I'm working with.  Here's the code I ended up with:

```java
public inherited sharing class LookupFieldsPickList extends VisualEditor.DynamicPickList {

    VisualEditor.DesignTimePageContext context;

    public LookupFieldsPicklist(VisualEditor.DesignTimePageContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override VisualEditor.DataRow getDefaultValue() {
        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows rows = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();

        List<String> keys = new List<String>();
        Map<String,String> fields = getLookupFields();
        for (String key : fields.keySet()) {
            keys.add(key);
        }

        VisualEditor.DataRow row = new VisualEditor.DataRow(fields.get(keys[0]), keys[0]);
        
        return row;
    }

    public override VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows getValues() {

        VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows rows = new VisualEditor.DynamicPickListRows();

        Map<String,String> fields = getLookupFields();
        for (String key : fields.keySet()) {
            VisualEditor.DataRow row = new VisualEditor.DataRow(fields.get(key), key);
            rows.addRow(row);
        }

        return rows;
    }

    private Map<String, String> getLookupFields() {

        Map<String,String> fieldMap = new Map<String,String>();

        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> describeResult = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(context.entityName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        for (String key : describeResult.keySet()) {
            DescribeFieldResult dfr = describeResult.get(key).getDescribe();
            String label = dfr.getLabel();
            Schema.DisplayType typeName = dfr.getType();
            
            if (Schema.DisplayType.REFERENCE == typeName) {
                List<SObjectType> oType = dfr.getReferenceTo();
                String oTypeName = oType[0].getDescribe().getName();
                System.debug('API name: ' + key + ';; label: ' + label + ';; type: ' + typeName + ' (' + oTypeName + ')');

                String fullName = label + ' (' + oTypeName + ')';
                fieldMap.put(oTypeName, fullName);
            }
        }

        return fieldMap;
    }


}
```

It needs to be cleaned up.  The `getDefaultValue` method is a bit brute-forceish, the values should be sorted alphabetically, etc.  But it gets me what I need to continue on.

Thanks for playing!